# How do you add a new line in an xpath expression?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

Given the following html content :

```
<div>
  <h3>Name :</h3>
  <p>Person A</p>
  <h3>Name :</h3>
  <p>Person B</p>
  <h3>Name :</h3>
  <p>Person c</p>
</div>
```

I need to extract the name of every person under the p tag using xPath. 
When I use the following expression :

```
name = container.xpath(".//h3[text()='Name :']/following-sibling::p/text()")
```

I get this output in a .csv file I am extracting:

```
Person A Person B Person C
```

But I need to have line breaks after every person, like this:

```
Person A
Person B
Person C
```

The code I use to get the csv file is as below:

```
with open("person.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in output:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Is there a way I can structure my xPath in order to achieve that?

Comment: It's probably not the fault of the xpath; can you post the actual code your are using to get to the csv?

Comment: sure, I'll do that in a minute

Comment: How does the `name` variable you use to store the XPath evaluation result relate to the `csv.DictWriter` code snippet? I don't see any use of  `name` in there. It might help if you post minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
name = container.xpath(".//h3[text()='Name :']/following-sibling::p/text()") 
names = ''
for n in name:
    names+=(n+'\n')
```

and use `names` in your `output` before you save to csv.